# How to reduce laravel load time in laravel when take big datas from database?

Tags: performance, laravel, load

Suppose I hit **/demo** url then it will go to controller n take data1 from database table which has 400 datas similarly data 2 which has 1200 datas.
Structure works this way first it go to controller take 1200+400 datas from db then go to view with  these 400+1200 datas n using foreach it shows 400 in modal1 n 1200 datas in modal2…it loads big data that’s way it loads slowly.thats why I try to split datas.so I used ajax for each button call but ajax call to controller works finely in localhost but not work in real ip.
Is there any better way /solution to reduce loading time??

**my structure**
**In controller**

```
$data1(here data is around 500)
$data2 (here data is around 1200)
return view(viewname’,compact('data1','data2'));
```

**In view**

```
<button class=”t1”>
<button class=”t2”>
@include(‘modal1’)
@include(‘modal2’)
```

**In modal1**

```
@foreach($data1 as $v)
{{$v->name}}
@endforeach
```

**In modal2**

```
@foreach($data1 as $v)
{{$v->name}}
@endforeach
```

here when i click button it opens modal1..n when i click another button it opens modal2.i used datatables in modal.(there is search,pagination)

Comment: Pagination is usually the way to reduce large chunks of data to more manageable sizes, but 500 or 1200 rows really isn't "big data".

Comment: may be its not big data ..........but its loading slowly...thats is very unefficient for user to wait until load

Comment: You should define "slowly" in a measure of time - 10 seconds, 100 ms? My point was that it __shouldn't be__ loading slowly. Make sure your data is indexed properly, enable some logging in essential spots, use the `EXPLAIN` mysql function (or whatever equivalent exists in your DBMS) and figure out what's slowing it down. By the way, are you by any chance using Vagrant with "shared folders" functionality? That tends to impact performance a lot, i.e. things should happen much faster on a live server than in a Vagrant box.

Comment: The reason it takes some time is probably because your browser needs to render a large amount of new HTML. @KaloyanDoichinov is right, you should use pagination the decrease the big chunk. Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination) for more info.

Comment: @KaloyanDoichinov i forget to  inform that i used datatables in modal...there is already pagination,search. no i did n't use vagrant...can i reduce loading intially??

Answer (score 1):

**There are number of things you have to consider to improve your Laravel website.**

Using eager loading in your application

Using ->cursor() in query insted of get() method.

**for example:**

```
    $data = DB::table("users")
    ->select('*')
    ->cursor();
```

**Use Caching**

```
$data_key = "any-key-variable";

    if (Cache::has($data_key)) {
          $getData = Cache::get($data_key);
    } 
   else {
     $getData = DB::table("users")
                    ->select('*')
                    ->cursor();
       Cache::put($data_key, $getData,720);
    }
```

}

**Also, Use this in your constructor in the controller or calling a function**

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

ini_set('max_execution_time', '3000');

ini_set('request_terminate_timeout', '3000');

**for example**

public function __construct()
{

```
           ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
           ini_set('max_execution_time', '3000');
           ini_set('request_terminate_timeout', '3000');             

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we use Datatable then all the data loads at first and then showed with pagination. This may take a lot of time if you have a huge amount of data. As you are using pagination, if data according to the pagination only shows then it will save your loading time.

You can use this package to solve this problem :
https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables